# Replace data between quotes in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to extract data between " " from a data file having delimiter as comma.

Sample input file:

```
,7/30/2019,7/31/2019,Wed,8/1/2019,FH/FN 30yr & 20yr TBA & Spec ,"10,000",8/13/2019,
```

Expected o/p:

```
,7/30/2019,7/31/2019,Wed,8/1/2019,FH/FN 30yr & 20yr TBA & Spec ,"10000",8/13/2019,
```

Comment: (1) Will there only be one pair of double quotes in one line? (2) Can there be higher numbers with multiple comma like `1,000,000`? (3) How far did your own attempts lead?

Comment: (1) Will there only be one pair of double quotes in one line? No , there can be many, but i am okay to replace the comma in between " " to a blank

 (2) Can there be higher numbers with multiple comma like 1,000,000? Yes. (3) How far did your own attempts lead? $ cat asdf
,7/30/2019,7/31/2019,Wed,8/1/2019,FH/FN 30yr & 20yr TBA & Spec ,"10,000",8/13/2019,
$ sed '/\"/,/\"/s/,//' asdf
7/30/2019,7/31/2019,Wed,8/1/2019,FH/FN 30yr & 20yr TBA & Spec ,"10,000",8/13/2019,
$

Comment: Do you need to replace all numbers with a "," in them?

Comment: I need to replace them with blank. "10,000" to "10000"

Comment: Is there a limit on the numbers (e.g. can 12,000,000,000,000 occur?), how many "," max?

Comment: @Ned64 Only inside double quotes, otherwise the delimiter comma in `2019,7` could get replaced! But it's still important whether there can by a field like `"Peter, Paul and Mary"` where the comma must not be replaced.

Comment: OK, what is the maximum number (highest number) to be changed?

Comment: I am not worried if "Peter, Paul and Mary" changes to "Peter Paul and Mary"

Comment: I am okay if all the comma in between " " gets changed to a blank

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this is properly formatted CSV (the example data looks ok in this respect), we can use `csvformat` from [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/) to temporarily change the field delimiters to some other character not otherwise present in the data, such as `@`, delete all commas, and change the field delimiter back to the default again:

```
$ csvformat -D '@' file.csv | tr -d , | csvformat -d '@'
,7/30/2019,7/31/2019,Wed,8/1/2019,FH/FN 30yr & 20yr TBA & Spec ,10000,8/13/2019,
```

The output does not have quotes around the field that we modified, but that's because it no longer needs it.

Obviously, "deleting all commas" may delete commas that we don't actually want to delete, so we can be a bit more selective and only delete the commas in the 7th field:

```
$ csvformat -D '@' file.csv | awk -F '@' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { gsub(",", "", $7); print }' | csvformat -d '@'
,7/30/2019,7/31/2019,Wed,8/1/2019,FH/FN 30yr & 20yr TBA & Spec ,10000,8/13/2019,
```

Answer (score 3):

Try  for example `awk`:

```
cat oldfile | awk '{ print gensub ("(,\"[0-9]+),([0-9][0-9][0-9]),?([0-9][0-9][0-9])?,?([0-9][0-9][0-9]),?","\\1\\2\\3\\4","g");}' > newfile
```

This works for large numbers, too.

**Explanation:**

`awk` is a programmable filter. The command given here in the commandline (between the outer single quotes "'") will be executed for every line of input from your file.

The awk program looks like this (different formatting):

```
{
    print gensub ("(,\"[0-9]+),([0-9][0-9][0-9]),?([0-9][0-9][0-9])?,?([0-9][0-9][0-9]),?",
                  "\\1\\2\\3\\4",
                  "g");
}
```

The `awk`-builtin command `gensub` replaces things given in the first argument, with the replacement given in the second.  If the third argument is a string starting with "g" or "G" it will replace all occurrences (tries until no more are found).

What is replaced?  The first argument is a regular expression (q.v.) in double quotes, here are the parts: `,\` then afterwards `[0-9]+` which means a digit 0-9 repeated one or more times (postfix operator `+`) then `,` which is just a character, then `[0-9][0-9][0-9]` and a comma `,` followed by a question mark `?` (you know what the first part means now but the postfix `?` is new - the comma digits can be omitted).  Then more digit groups and commas which may be omitted - this is for larger numbers.

In this explanation I have left out the parentheses `(` and `)` so far! These mark those things that are matched by the expression but remembered. In the second argument to `gensub` we reference the first `\1` through fourth `\4` things that were matched (the numbers) and print them out again here.

Comment: Thanks this worked. But i am not able to understand how it is working. Could you please explain?

Comment: OK, but only if you mark then answer as working :-)

Comment: :-) :-) I did.. Of course i will do. :-)

Comment: @Ramkumar Explanation OK?

Comment: @Jesse_b Thanks. That's why I asked about the maximum number in the beginning.

Comment: @Ned64 Consider me as a beginner :-). I was trying to understand your explanation, but have few doubts. Can u tell how many arguments you passed to gensub function. Can you split and mention them as 1 2 3 .. Please

Comment: I added more explanations but could not save the answer (error message by website).

Comment: @Ramkumar OK, typed most of the things a second time, there are more details now. I believe this is as much as can be explained inside an Answer.  Do feel free to ask specifics but you may need to read up on regular expressions by yourself - that would be beyond an SE Answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another `awk` solution:

```
awk -F\" '{
    OFS="\"";
    for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
        if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
            gsub(/,/, "", $i)
        }
    }
}1' input.csv
```

This will use the double quote as a field separator and loop through all fields.  If the field number is an even number (which is not fool-proof, but given your example it should mean that the field exists between quotes) it will remove any commas from that field.  The `1` will cause `awk` to print everything (with the changes made) using the double quote as the output field separator.

In use:

```
$ cat input.csv
,7/30/2019,7/31/2019,Wed,8/1/2019,FH/FN 30yr & 20yr TBA & Spec ,"10,000",8/13/2019,
,7/30/2019,7/31/2019,"100",FH/FN 30yr & 20yr TBA & Spec ,"10,000,000",8/13/2019,
,7/30/2019,7/31/2019,"Jack, Mary, and Jane",8/1/2019,"123,456,789,012,345,678","10,000",8/13/2019,
$ awk -F\" '{
>     OFS="\"";
>     for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
>         if ( i % 2 == 0 ) {
>             gsub(/,/, "", $i)
>         }
>     }
> }1' input.csv
,7/30/2019,7/31/2019,Wed,8/1/2019,FH/FN 30yr & 20yr TBA & Spec ,"10000",8/13/2019,
,7/30/2019,7/31/2019,"100",FH/FN 30yr & 20yr TBA & Spec ,"10000000",8/13/2019,
,7/30/2019,7/31/2019,"Jack Mary and Jane",8/1/2019,"123456789012345678","10000",8/13/2019,
```

**NOTE:** This *will* remove the commas in fields that are not numbers.  In order to read this file correctly as a csv you will need to do that.  If for some reason you want to retain those commas you can use the below solution.

---

```
awk -F\" '{
    OFS="\"";
    for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) {
        if ( i % 2 == 0 && $i ~ /[0-9]/ ) {
            gsub(/,/, "", $i)
        }
    }
}1' input.csv
```

Comment: This will not work correctly if there are non-numbers in quotation marks. These are not to be changed.  Anyway, why write the same thing again I already answered?

Comment: I thought, the more precise, the better.

Comment: @Ned64: I don't disagree, but this site encourages multiple answers to a single problem.

Comment: Upon thinking about it further, it seems like OP is trying to make this a readable csv file, so having commas within **any** field would be undesirable, whether that field is a number or not.  It seems the correct thing to do is to remove the commas between `Jack, Mary, and Jane` otherwise that will be split into 3 separate fields when read as a CSV.

Comment: No, if the commas are between quotes "" they will be ignored as field delimiters. That's likely the reason why the quotes are there in the first place, even though they are unusual around a number.

Comment: @Ned64: That may be true for some applications but absolutely is not true for all applications, `awk` being one of them.

Comment: awk is not made with CSV files in mind and works badly with it. Office and mathematics programs read them just fine.

Comment: Opinionated and wrong.  However the most obvious reason OP is trying to remove these commas is because whatever program OP is using to read this file is having issues with them.

Comment: Why are you only considering every other column only?

Comment: @Ned64 Because as long as the column is enclosed in quotes we only want to modify every other column.  The odd numbered columns are the ones that _do not_ appear between quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed 's/\(\".*\),\(.*\"\)/\1\2/' file
```

Comment: This will only replace one comma and will make a mess when there are more double quotes on that line.

Comment: @Philippos Agreed with the comma, I'll keep working and edit if necessary, although OP data does not show any other double quotes.

Comment: @Philippos If it works for the data the OP has it could be OK? I tried a more specific answer, let's see what Ramkumar thinks.

Comment: As Philippos said if i have another data after "10,000", it failed. But thanks for responding. I am taking Ned64 syntax. $ cat asdf
,7/30/2019,7/31/2019,"Wed",8/1/2019,"FH/FN 30yr & 20yr TBA & Spec" ,"10,000",8/13/2019,"ram",
$ sed 's/\(\".*\),\(.*\"\)/\1\2/' asdf
,7/30/2019,7/31/2019,"Wed",8/1/2019,"FH/FN 30yr & 20yr TBA & Spec" ,"10,000",8/13/2019"ram",

Comment: You need to replace the `.*` by `[^"]*` to avoid those problems and add a loop to cover higher numbers; see my answer for that. I don't like using loops, but at least they are less complicated as the `awk` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your own attempt `sed '/\"/,/\"/s/,//'` fails because the address range you give only filters for a range of lines, not a range inside a line.

This type of task is nasty in standard `sed`. If it's just about one comma, then `sed -E 's/("[0-9]*),([0-9]*")/\1 \2/` would do the trick, but for multiple comma you'd have to loop, giving ugly results like

```
sed -Ee :loop -e 's/("[0-9 ]*),([^"]*")/\1 \2/;tloop'
```

The `("[0-9]*)` matches the opening double quote followed by any number of digits and will be referred to as `\1` in the replacement, the `([^"]*")` matches anything after the comma until the closing `"`, so `\1 \2` is the same, but with the first comma replaced.

Now the `t` command branches to the `loop` mark if a replacement was made. This gets repeated until there is no comma left to be replaced.

This even works for cases with more than one number with as many commas as you like: `,7/30/2019,"99,999,999,999,999",0,1 ,"10,000","foo, bar"` will get transformed to `,7/30/2019,"99 999 999 999 999" 0 1  "10 000" "foo, bar"`