# Sed substitute pattern with command

Tags: sed

A propo of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534718/replace-data-between-quotes-in-a-file/534720#534723).

Let's say I want to substitute `<number with commas>` for `<number>` in string `something, "10,000", something`.

Number could be `1,000`, `10,000`... so on.

I was experimenting if it's possible to use a command for the substitution:

```
echo 'something, "10,000", something' | sed "s/\(\".*\"\)/$(echo \\1 | sed 's/,//')/"
```

Which doesn't work, nothing happens.

What triggers my question is that if I only use `echo`

```
echo 'something, "10,000", something' | sed "s/\(\".*\"\)/$(echo \\1)/"
```

the parameter `\\1` is read OK, but it looks like it can't be piped to `sed` (or `grep`).

Is this possible in some way?

Comment: The command substitution in the replacement part of your `sed` command is executed before the `sed` command runs.

Comment: .. which means it will sed the string '\1' and not the actual captured string.

Comment: @JonasBerlin That was my conclusion, what loses me is that `echo \\1` outputs the captured pattern, not the string "\1"

Comment: yeah the `\1` gets used in the main sed command replacement part as-is and thus the replacement becomes the captured group's contents.

Comment: @guillermochamorro `echo \\1` does not output the captured pattern. It outputs `\1`.  This is inserted into the replacement part of the substitution command as if it had been `\1` all along.

Comment: I'd suggest that you try running your pipelines with `set -x` activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansion of the command substitution that is part of your `sed` expression happens before the `sed` command is executed.

This means that the shell, to execute the command

```
sed "s/\(\".*\"\)/$(echo \\1 | sed 's/,//')/"
```

first runs

```
echo \\1 | sed 's/,//'
```

This outputs `\1` since there are no commas in the string outputted by `echo`.

The shell then inserts this string where the command substitution was, yielding

```
sed "s/\(\".*\"\)/\1/"
```

This is also clear if we run the pipeline with tracing enabled in the shell:

```
$ set -x
$ echo 'something, "10,000", something' | sed "s/\(\".*\"\)/$(echo \\1 | sed 's/,//')/"
+ echo 'something, "10,000", something'
+ echo '\1'
+ sed s/,//
+ sed 's/\(".*"\)/\1/'
something, "10,000", something
```

In your second pipeline, the same thing happens (minus the execution of `sed 's/,//'`):

```
$ set -x
$ echo 'something, "10,000", something' | sed "s/\(\".*\"\)/$(echo \\1)/"
+ echo 'something, "10,000", something'
+ echo '\1'
+ sed 's/\(".*"\)/\1/'
something, "10,000", something
```

In conclusion: It is *not* possible to call another shell command from within `sed` using command substitutions to process a substring matched by a regular expression, as the command substitutions are processed before `sed` is called (in order to resolve what the `sed` editing script is before calling `sed`).

`sed` moreover does not provide any mechanism in its language to call out to another command, like some other editing/processing languages do (e.g. the rudimentary `r` and `w` commands in the `ed` editor allows this, as does `awk`).

Comment: With GNU `sed` one could do e.g. `echo 'something, "10,000", something' | sed 's/.*"\([[:digit:]]\+\),\?.*/seq \1/e'`. The `e` can be used as a flag for the `s` function or as a standalone function

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
sed 's/\([0-9]\),\([0-9]\)/\1\2/g'
```

This works only if there are at least two numbers between two commas, so

```
123,456,789 -> 123456789
12,34,56,78 -> 12345678
but
1,2,3,4,5,6 -> 12,34,56
```

Comment: `sed -e :top -e 's/\([[:digit:]]\),\([[:digit:]]\)/\1\2/g; ttop'`